# cannot resolve '`Column_Name`' given input columns: Error: Pyspark Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate-functions, pyspark

Can someone Please help me how should i Implemnet below sql in Pyspark Dataframe.

```
    (SUM(Cash) /SUM(cash + credit)) * 100 AS Percentage,
        
    df1=df.withColumn("cash_credit",sf.col("cash") + sf.col("credit")) 
    df1.show(5)

    -------------+---------------+ +--------+-------+------+------| 
    Credit        |Cash   |       MTH|YR           |  cash_credit | 
    -------------+---------------+ -------+--------|--------------|
     100.00|       400.00|         10|       2019  |  500.00      | 
     0.00  |       500.00|         6 |       2019  |  500.00      |  
     200.00|       600.00|         12|       2018  |  800.00      | 
     0.00  |       0.00  |         10|       2019  |  0.00        | 
     300.00|       700.00|          7|       2019  |  1000.00     | 
    -------------+---------------+----------+--------+-------+--- |
```

I have tried below Pyspark Code.

```
    df2 = df1.groupBy('MTH', 'YR').agg(sf.sum("Cash").alias("sum_Cash"))\
             .withColumn("final_column",sf.col("sum_Cash") + sf.col("cash_credit"))\
             .withColumn("div",sf.col("sum_Cash")/sf.col("final_column"))\
             .withColumn("Percentage",sf.col("div")*100)
```

But not able to execute it. It's showing below error.

```
    cannot resolve '`cash_credit`' given input columns: [MTH, YR, sum_Cash];;
```

Comment: Your LOGIC is wrong.  When you `groupBy('MTH', 'YR').agg(sf.sum("Cash").alias("sum_Cash"))` you will have only `MTH, YR, sum_Cash` .

Comment: @Sanket9394 Thanks a lot.could you Please help me how should i Rewrite this.

Comment: You need to pass this - cash_credit Inside agg function else it will not available to access subsequent steps..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify it like this to bring cash_credit out of groupby-aggregation:

```
df2 = df1.groupBy('MTH', 'YR').agg(sf.sum("Cash").alias("sum_Cash"),sf.sum("cash_credit").alias("cash_credit"))\
         .withColumn("final_column",sf.col("sum_Cash") + sf.col("cash_credit"))\
         .withColumn("div",sf.col("sum_Cash")/sf.col("final_column"))\
         .withColumn("Percentage",sf.col("div")*100)
```

I uses sum aggregation for 'cash_credit' but you can use other aggregation functions.